# I accidentally deleted things from my PATH. What do I do?

Tags: java, path, environment-variables, environment

I was facing some problems while setting up Flutter on my PC, apparently, something called a Java SDK was missing so I downloaded it but it still wasn't working so I followed this dude's tutorial on Youtube according to which I had to edit my PATH. I edited it, during which I accidentally deleted something from there. The problem still wasn't solved and now something is missing from my PATH. I'm very new to development so I have no idea as to what I should do. I'm attaching screenshots, can someone please look at them and tell me if something is missing or if something extra is present? The Java thing still isn't working and it says that JAVA_HOME is pointing towards the wrong directory.

Pictures attached:
[User variables](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SWPCk.png)
[System variables](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2w2y4.png)

Comment: My answer is on basis of image you had 2-3 min ago, saw wrong java home path there.

Answer (score 1):

Don’t include the \bin folder, just the JDK path. For example

```
1   Correct – C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_60
2   Wrong – C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_60\bin
```

More details available on 
[this](https://mkyong.com/java/how-to-set-java_home-on-windows-10/)